# Should we have a FAQ for false proofs?

Tags: discussion

Should we have a question listing known false proofs, and other fallacies? Like an official FAQ version of [113](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-are-some-classic-fallacious-proofs)? Then for all instances of questions like [389180](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389180/what-is-wrong-in-this-proof), [388435](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388435/seems-that-i-just-proved-2-4) and so on, we can just redirect them and close it. Like Qiaochu says, duplicates of these are hard to search for, although we're sure they exist.

We could probably draw on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy, and other existing such collections.

Comment: If you believe they're indeed FAQs, list them [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868), and then tag the question(s) in main with [tag:faq].

Comment: @J.M. I do not believe that any single one of these questions has been asked frequently, or even occasionally. And I'm not sure how to generalize them to one question.

Comment: I don't think putting them into a single question would make it any easier to detect duplicates.  My opinion is that having a `fake-proofs` tag is enough.  If there were some way to support a message saying "have you checked in the `fake-proofs` tag" popping up whenever somebody put the phrase "What's wrong with" or "where does __- fail" in a title box, that might help.